# Get Order Item Status in Magento REST API

Tags: magento

It is stated in [Magento REST API Documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Orders/order_items.html) that attribute **status** is included when retrieving order items (GET http://magentohost/api/rest/orders/410/items).

But when I tried the above request, status is not present. I am using **admin** authentication. I have tried selecting All in Rest Attributes, but still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try /rest/default/V1/orders/items/:order_id to get the order item details